# Angular2 customize modal body

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-modal

I have an Angular2 App that can show a modal. For that i call an injectable method inside a Js class:

```
@Injectable()
public showErrorDialog(errorMessage:string, isError:boolean) {

    this.modal.alert()
    .size('sm')
    .showClose(true)
    .title("Modal Title")
    .body(errorMessage)
    .open();
}
```

Now i would customize body of modal, by changing background, and text style.
How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options - are you using this via a component? You could add the styles or styleUrl property (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html). Alternatively you could also take a look at how the modal is constructed using Chrome's Developer tool (or your preferred browser's developer tool) and find out what classes are being used by the modal and add a custom css file to set your desired values.

Comment: i'm using inside app.component (the main component of whole app)

Comment: You could try to add something like this to your component -> style: [' .text-intro span { color: #0f0;} '] - this should change the title to be green. As I said earlier use the chrome dev tool to check what elements you can style.